# Why are older versions of IE 'needed' to be account for in web development and not Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I am still new to web development so please bear with me.

I was curious as to why I see that Internet Explorer has older versions that people need to adhere to whilst developing websites? Moreover, what I am really looking for is the answer as to why this isn't the case for Chrome, Firefox and Safari?

Do Chrome and Firefox require update as a necessity where IE instead just brings out new versions?

Perhaps there are other versions of Firefox/Chrome/etc. that need to be accounted for I am just unaware?

I can see that IE8 was made 5 years ago and is still used by 10% of the world at the link below. This is one version I understand 'needs' to be accounted for in development but again, I am unsure as to why this is the case for IE more over other browsers.

http://theie8countdown.com/

Apologies if this is a '*bad*' question but I would like to know.

Comment: Because IE8 doesn't prompt you to upgrade to IE11 (and it can't be upgraded to IE11 in windows XP). When there is a new firefox version, firefox prompts you to install it. Google automatically updates itself every time you close it. There are a few older versions of firefox though that people have hung onto for some reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprises build applications to the standards available at the time. They often never upgrade these applications, but they are critical to their business operations. Most of the time the application is handed over to the IT guys and they deploy it to a server and ultimately loose the source code, etc. The IT guys often do not catalog applications, etc and enterprises really just eventually get to a point where they hope the server hosting the application does not die or they loose the applications.

What does that mea to web developers? Since the applications were written to standards before the mortgage crisis enterprises standardize on Internet Explorer 8 and web developers are stuck. Luckily the latest version of Internet Explorer includes Enterprise Mode. This is a pure IE 8 emulation mode with some improvements. The JavaScript engine is faster and it runs within the IE 11 security boundary. The IT Admins can centrally manage what domains are rendered using this enterprise mode. It is a pure emulator and includes support for some edge cases that kept some enterprises from upgraded (things like complete ActiveX support and CSS expressions). You can read more about enterprise mode. http://love2dev.com/#!article/Internet-Explorer-Enterprise-Mode-Resources

The idea is enterprise will feel safe to finally upgrade to IE 11 and we as developers can move on. Since most companies are at least using Windows 7 and XP is officially dead this is a very attractive feature that Chrome and FireFox simply do not offer.

Oh and the reason enterprises use IE instead of Chrome and FireFox is the ability to integrate global access policies, Active Directory and more security. Chrome and FireFox do not offer enterprise grade features like these.